# Can I quickly disable access point radios in one building through Cisco Prime Infrastructure or wism-2 interface

Tags: cisco

We are hosting a robotics competition and they require that all of our wireless AP's be disabled for the weekend. I am wondering if there is a way to do this from our management software. Added difficulty: on a per-building basis. So far, I have found that I can do it for an entire controller using the WiSM-2 web interface and disabling the network status of the radios. I can also do it via Prime Infrastructure using configuration templates. Unfortunately, both of these solutions affect ALL access points, nut just one building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it in Prime Infrastructure 2.0:
1.) Switch to classic theme
2.) Choose Configure -> Lightweight AP configuration templates
3.) Create a new template & edit it
4.) Under the AP Parameters tab check the box for Admin status and leave enabled un-checked
5.) Go the the Select APs tab and choose your APs
6.) Go to the apply/schedule tab and save it, then apply it.

Viola!